# Eror while connecting to WCF service from .NET Core MVC application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-core

There following error is generated while adding the .NET 4.6 WCF Service reference to a .NET Core 2.2 MVC application.

> Importing web service metadata ... Number of service endpoints found:
>   1 Scaffolding service reference code ... Restoring NuGet packages for
>   bootstrapper ... Warning:Warning:
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade:
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration from 3.0.0 to 2.2.0. Reference the
>   package directly from the project to select a different version. 
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605:  SvcutilBootstrapper ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore 3.0.3 ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 3.0.0) 
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605:  SvcutilBootstrapper ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 2.2.0)
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade:
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions from 3.0.0 to 2.2.0.
>   Reference the package directly from the project to select a different
>   version. 
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605:  SvcutilBootstrapper ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore 3.0.3 ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions (>= 3.0.0) 
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605:  SvcutilBootstrapper ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions (>= 2.2.0)
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade:
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder from 3.0.0 to 2.2.4.
>   Reference the package directly from the project to select a different
>   version. 
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605:  SvcutilBootstrapper ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore 3.0.3 ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder (>= 3.0.0) 
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605:  SvcutilBootstrapper ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder (>= 2.2.4)
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade:
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging from 3.0.0 to 2.2.0. Reference the
>   package directly from the project to select a different version. 
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605:  SvcutilBootstrapper ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore 3.0.3 ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging (>= 3.0.0) 
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605:  SvcutilBootstrapper -> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
>   (>= 2.2.0)   Restore failed in 916.37 ms for
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj.
>   Building bootstrapper project ... Error:Error: Microsoft (R) Build
>   Engine version 16.4.0+e901037fe for .NET Core Copyright (C) Microsoft
>   Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade:
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration from 3.0.0 to 2.2.0. Reference the
>   package directly from the project to select a different version. 
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605:  SvcutilBootstrapper ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore 3.0.3 ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 3.0.0) 
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605:  SvcutilBootstrapper ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 2.2.0)
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade:
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions from 3.0.0 to 2.2.0.
>   Reference the package directly from the project to select a different
>   version. 
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605:  SvcutilBootstrapper ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore 3.0.3 ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions (>= 3.0.0) 
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605:  SvcutilBootstrapper ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions (>= 2.2.0)
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade:
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder from 3.0.0 to 2.2.4.
>   Reference the package directly from the project to select a different
>   version. 
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605:  SvcutilBootstrapper ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore 3.0.3 ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder (>= 3.0.0) 
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605:  SvcutilBootstrapper ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder (>= 2.2.4)
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade:
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging from 3.0.0 to 2.2.0. Reference the
>   package directly from the project to select a different version. 
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605:  SvcutilBootstrapper ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore 3.0.3 ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging (>= 3.0.0) 
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605:  SvcutilBootstrapper -> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
>   (>= 2.2.0)
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade:
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration from 3.0.0 to 2.2.0. Reference the
>   package directly from the project to select a different version. 
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605:  SvcutilBootstrapper ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore 3.0.3 ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 3.0.0) 
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605:  SvcutilBootstrapper ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 2.2.0)
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade:
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions from 3.0.0 to 2.2.0.
>   Reference the package directly from the project to select a different
>   version. 
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605:  SvcutilBootstrapper ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore 3.0.3 ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions (>= 3.0.0) 
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605:  SvcutilBootstrapper ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions (>= 2.2.0)
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade:
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder from 3.0.0 to 2.2.4.
>   Reference the package directly from the project to select a different
>   version. 
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605:  SvcutilBootstrapper ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore 3.0.3 ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder (>= 3.0.0) 
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605:  SvcutilBootstrapper ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder (>= 2.2.4)
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade:
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging from 3.0.0 to 2.2.0. Reference the
>   package directly from the project to select a different version. 
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605:  SvcutilBootstrapper ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore 3.0.3 ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging (>= 3.0.0) 
>   C:\Users\RTYEY\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2020_Jan_29_16_43_21\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcutilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1605:  SvcutilBootstrapper -> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
>   (>= 2.2.0)
>       0 Warning(s)
>       4 Error(s)
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:00.55
>
> An error occurred while bootstrapping svcutil. This usually happens
>   when processing references.  You might be able to work around this
>   problem by not providing reference parameters, and manually removing
>   any types redefined in the generated proxy code. Done.

I was able to connect to the service using a Win 7 machine. Now we moved to Win10 and I am getting there error. From my back up from Win 7, I am able to compile, but it wont connect to service asaying that there was no endpoint listening or an invalid operation.

Comment: Have you tried to add connected service again by means of Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider? By default, the service’s related settings locate in the Reference.cs file. The automatically generated service address is Localhost instead of the practical service address, we need to change it to the actual service address.
After you move the project to the new machine, please ensure that the network is unblocked between the service and the client’s project. I would like to know which binding the WCF service use. Do we need to provide certain credentials?

Comment: I tried by using the GUI. from connected services (like .net framework) by providing the svc url. But after sometime the error got generated and no reference file generated

Comment: I suspect there is something wrong with the client project. Have you tried to call the service in a DotNet framework project? As you know, the client-oriented WCF built on DotNet Core just is a compatible solution, not fully support.
https://github.com/dotnet/wcf
What’s the configuration on the server-side? I would like to reproduce your issue on my side in order to check if it supports in the Core project. Moreover, please try to call the service in DotNet Core3.1 SDK.

Comment: However I was able to user dotnet-svcutil tool to generate reference class. Trying on this one and will get back an update. github discussion were messy as it loops through one solution to another

Comment: If you can generate proxy classes and configurations through Dotnet-svcutil, then this should work. Because VS adds the service reference does not necessarily use the latest SvcUtil, it depends on the Visual Studio version/DotNet Core SDK (the preview version should be the latest). Put the proxy class and configuration in the project to see if the service can be called successfully.

Comment: Yes It works, but I need to tweak some code using Factory to generate proxy and finally invoke the call. Some code refactoring required. Also needs to try with a generic func method to create the bindings etc.

Comment: That should be easy. Generating the channel factory requires binding that is consistent with the server, and you can refer to the binding configuration in the configuration file to use the channel factory call.